# Building Nutch Plugin: class dependency

Tags: java, ant, nutch

I wrote some Nutch plugin with using different extension points such as Protocol, Parser and etc. These plugins work perfectly inside eclipse. But in order to use them on hadoop cluster it should be built by using ANT. My problem is, I wrote some classes in some new packages inside core folder(src). These classes are shared cross different developed plugins. My problem is at build time of developed plugins, ANT can not find the mentioned shared classes, so I am unable to complete the build process successfully. For better understanding of my problem Here is build.xml of one of my plugins:

```
<project name="filter-news" default="jar-core">

  <import file="../build-plugin.xml"/>

    <!-- Build compilation dependencies -->
        <target name="deps-jar">
          <ant target="jar" inheritall="false" dir="../lib-xml"/>
        </target>

        <!-- Add compilation dependencies to classpath -->
        <path id="plugin.deps">
          <fileset dir="${nutch.root}/build">
            <include name="**/lib-xml/*.jar" />
          </fileset>
        </path>

        <!-- Deploy Unit test dependencies -->
  <!-- Deploy Unit test dependencies -->

  <!-- for junit test -->

</project>
```

ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
  <info organisation="org.apache.nutch" module="${ant.project.name}">
    <license name="Apache 2.0"/>
    <ivyauthor name="Apache Nutch Team" url="http://nutch.apache.org"/>
    <description>
        Apache Nutch
    </description>
  </info>

  <configurations>
    <include file="../../..//ivy/ivy-configurations.xml"/>
  </configurations>

  <publications>
    <!--get the artifact from our module name-->
    <artifact conf="master"/>
  </publications>

  <dependencies>
<dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.31"/>
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner" name="htmlcleaner" rev="2.2"/>
<dependency org="commons-jxpath" name="commons-jxpath" rev="1.3"/>

  </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

plugin.xml:

```
<plugin id="filter-news" name="Apache Nutch XML/HTML Parser/Indexing Filter" version="1.4" provider-name="nutch.org">

    <runtime>
        <library name="filter-news.jar">
            <export name="*"/>
        </library>
        <library name="ant-1.7.0.jar"/>
        <library name="ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar"/>
        <library name="jdom-1.1.jar"/>
        <library name="commons-jxpath-1.3.jar"/>
        <library name="htmlcleaner-2.2.jar"/>
        <library name="mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar"/>
    </runtime>

    <requires>
        <import plugin="nutch-extensionpoints"/>
    </requires>

    <extension id="org.apache.nutch.parse" name="Nutch XML/HTML Html parser filter" point="org.apache.nutch.parse.HtmlParseFilter">
        <implementation id="com.ictcert.nutch.filter.news.NewsHtmlFilter"                       class="com.ictcert.nutch.filter.news.NewsHtmlFilter" />
    </extension>
    <extension id="org.apache.nutch.indexer" name="Nutch XML/HTML Indexing Filter" point="org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilter">
        <implementation id="com.ictcert.nutch.filter.news.NewsIndexingFilter" class="com.ictcert.nutch.filter.news.NewsIndexingFilter"/>
    </extension>

</plugin>
```

When I try to build this plugin ant can not find all of the class dependencies related to `com.ictcert.nutch` package which is located in core part of nutch (src). While for other classes located in `org.apache.nutch` I have not such problem. Would you please tell me what is wrong with my configuration that the default packages could be found by ANT but the new ones could not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from my experience the implementation id should have the same package structure as your extension point. Can you try that and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you know where can I change the package structure? Probably there is ant config for this purpose.

Comment: Instead of putting your filter at 'com.ictcert.nutch.filter.news' in eclipse.You should put it under 'org.apache.nutch.parse.news'

Comment: When I tried to create a jar file from core sources ant put them into lib directory the problem solved. I dont think it is a limitation of nutch, I think there is some problem with my build.xml or ANT configuration and it should be solved. There is no such limitation in java that your package structure should be same across project.

Comment: That is really good to know. I did not say that it is a limitation of java, I thought it was a limitation of nutch. Can you double check and run the crawler. Just to make sure your configuration will run

Comment: Dear @ameertawfik, yeah it works, but I dont want to change the package names since it makes my code distinguishable from nutch base. Therefore there should  be some configuration related to nutch/ANT. I am looking for that configuration.